# How to put a variable into a filename in powershell

Tags: powershell, filenames

I'm trying to append a variable to the beginning of a filename. The solutions I've seen all use a "+" to concatenate, but this is giving me errors. I suspect it's that the variable isn't being recognized as a string. But I don't know how to fix that. And maybe that's not the problem.

Here was one attempt:

```
$JobNum = (get-item $Path).parent.parent.parent
Get-ChildItem Of*.pdf | rename-item -newname { $JobNum + "_"+ $_.name }
```

The error was : "The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed. Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Here was another. This one I added a string to $JobNum to try to force powershell to see it as a string and I put a static jobnumber on the file first then tried to replace it.

```
$JobNum = -join ((get-item $Path ).parent.parent.parent , "_")
Get-ChildItem Of*.pdf | rename-item -newname { $_.Name -replace 'O', '99999_O' }
Get-ChildItem 99999* | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "99999_", $JobNum }
```

The error was "Cannot rename the specified target, because it represents a path or device name.

Any help is appreciated.

Additional Information:
$JobNum | Get-Member

Name                      MemberType     Definition

---

LinkType                  CodeProperty   System.String LinkType{get=GetLinkType;}
Mode                      CodeProperty   System.String Mode{get=Mode;}
ModeWithoutHardLink       CodeProperty   System.String ModeWithoutHardLink{get=ModeWithoutHardLink;}
Target                    CodeProperty   System.String Target{get=GetTarget;}
Create                    Method         void Create()
CreateSubdirectory        Method         System.IO.DirectoryInfo CreateSubdirectory(string path)
Delete                    Method         void Delete(), void Delete(bool recursive)
EnumerateDirectories      Method         System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[System.IO.DirectoryInfo] EnumerateDirec…
EnumerateFiles            Method         System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[System.IO.FileInfo] EnumerateFiles(), S…
EnumerateFileSystemInfos  Method         System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[System.IO.FileSystemInfo] EnumerateFile…
Equals                    Method         bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetDirectories            Method         System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] GetDirectories(), System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] GetDirec…
GetFiles                  Method         System.IO.FileInfo[] GetFiles(), System.IO.FileInfo[] GetFiles(string searchPa…
GetFileSystemInfos        Method         System.IO.FileSystemInfo[] GetFileSystemInfos(), System.IO.FileSystemInfo[] Ge…
GetHashCode               Method         int GetHashCode()
GetLifetimeService        Method         System.Object GetLifetimeService()
GetObjectData             Method         void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System…
GetType                   Method         type GetType()
InitializeLifetimeService Method         System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()
MoveTo                    Method         void MoveTo(string destDirName)
Refresh                   Method         void Refresh()
ToString                  Method         string ToString()
Attributes                Property       System.IO.FileAttributes Attributes {get;set;}
CreationTime              Property       datetime CreationTime {get;set;}

Comment: What is $Path?  Is it a string or object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J Web, is $JobNum a string or some kind of object?

I was able to make your original syntax work when $JobNum is a string.

```
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local> $JobNum = "Job001"
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local>
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local>
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local>
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local> Get-ChildItem .\*.jpg

    Directory: C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/21/2019  12:13 PM         153628 WebEx-20190221-2.JPG
-a----        2/21/2019  12:14 PM         165229 WebEx-20190221-3.JPG
-a----        2/21/2019  12:12 PM         100058 WebEx-20190221.JPG

PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local>
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local>
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local>
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local> Get-ChildItem .\*.jpg | Rename-item -NewName { $JobNum + "_" + $_.Name }
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local>
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local>
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local>
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local> Get-ChildItem .\*.jpg


    Directory: C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2/21/2019  12:13 PM         153628 Job001_WebEx-20190221-2.JPG
-a----        2/21/2019  12:14 PM         165229 Job001_WebEx-20190221-3.JPG
-a----        2/21/2019  12:12 PM         100058 Job001_WebEx-20190221.JPG


PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local>
```

To determine what $JobNum looks like, run this command:

```
PS C:\Users\vvangor001\documents\Scripts - Local> $JobNum | Get-Member


   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()
...
```

In the example above, we can see that $JobNum is  a string.

Comment: Hi. $JobNum is a folder name, so I *think* it's a string, but I don't know. If I echo it I get "78780". If it's an object, how would I alter my code to use Get-Member? Like this? Get-ChildItem 99999* | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace "99999_", $JobNum | Get-Member} Or, better yet, is there a way to cast it as a string, since that's how I'm trying to use it?

Comment: Can you please run `$JobNum | Get-Member` and post the full output so we can see the properties, methods, etc?  Based on the results, we'll have a better idea about how convert it to a string whether by using a baked-in method (e.g. .ToString) or by pulling a specific property from the object (e.g. Name).

Comment: Another command that might be handy to run is this:
`$JobNum | Select-Object -Property *`  This will show you the properties and values of those properties.

Comment: Both command produce more output than I can post in a comment. Is there a particular property I can post the value for that will clarify things? Alternately, if we just assume this isn't a string, is there a way to cast it as a string? Thanks

Comment: Hmmm... Good question. I did some googling , but I didn't see a good solution.   Can you update your original question by appending the output of the command at the bottom of your post with the title that's something like "Additional Information...."?

Otherwise, just temporarily post it to Google Drive, DropBox, etc, and post the link.  I'll take a look at the output and see if I can give you a better answer, and when we're done, you can just delete the link.  How's that sound?

Comment: What I've added is as much as the form is allowing me to put in. I'll see if there's a way I can use dropbox or google drive. I think both raise alarm bells due to the data I work with, so have to chat with someone in security. In the meantime, if anyone knows of a way to force a variable to be seen as a string, that might be the easiest answer.

Comment: OK, try this one `$JobNum | Select-Object -Property *` and see if the folder name that you're expecting is stored as a property.  And if so, reference that property instead of the whole object (e.g. $JobNum.Property1)

Comment: the string I'm looking for is in the name property. When I run $JobNum.name | Select-Object -Property * I only get that the length is 5.

Comment: @JWeb, if I'm understanding you correctly, then this might solve your problem `Get-ChildItem Of*.pdf | rename-item -newname { $JobNum.name + "_"+ $_.name }`

Comment: @JWeb, was that you that marked this as the answer?  If so, did the previous suggestion do the trick?

Comment: Using $JobNum.name did the trick. Thank you very, very much.